# tikz inverted clipping of named paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I'm trying to employ the extremely cool inverted clipping from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz) in combination with reusage of named paths with the `use path` key I stole from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301335/tikz-even-odd-clipping-using-named-path-by-intersections-library). However, it seems like my cargo-cult skills of stealing TikZ code from stackexchange are insufficient here, because in the MWE I constructed, the inversion of the clipping does not work as expected:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{invclip/.style={clip,insert path={{[reset cm]
      (-16383.99999pt,-16383.99999pt) rectangle (16383.99999pt,16383.99999pt)
}}}}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  use path for main/.code={%
    \tikz@addmode{%
      \expandafter\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@#1\endcsname
    }%
  },
  use path for actions/.code={%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@preactions\expandafter{\tikz@preactions\expandafter\let\expandafter\tikz@actions@path\csname tikz@intersect@path@name@#1\endcsname}%
  },
  use path/.style={%
    use path for main=#1,
    use path for actions=#1,
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0mm]
  \coordinate (A) at (-1,-1);
  \coordinate (B) at (1,-1);
  \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (D) at (-1,1);
  \path[draw=black,name path=P] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) --cycle;
  \begin{scope}
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox} % useful to avoid the rectangle in the bounding box
      \path[invclip] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D); % works just fine
      %\path[invclip,use path=P]; % doesn't work at all
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox} 
  \fill[orange!50] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

This works just fine:

[image: this works]

But this doesn't work:

[image: this doesn't work]

How can I use inverted clipping with `use path`?

Comment: In this example, of course, you could draw what you need much more easily. But I assume your real case is not so simple.

Comment: Yes, my actual case involves very complicated paths instead of rectangles, but is conceptually the same (an inner shape, an outer shape, and I want to fill just the area between the two).

Comment: Then why not just use the `even odd rule`?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the saved paths. This doesn't work even if you substitute in the original path specifications rather than reusing them.

Comment: To get it to work without saving paths, you need to eliminate the use of `rectangle` and specify it explicitly. At least, that's what I found.

Comment: Not sure what to make of this. Are you saying that there's a clash between saving paths and inverted clipping? Because that's what I find, see here: http://mathb.in/149713

Comment: That seems to be true, but also irrelevant in your example. That doesn't work even if you take the saved paths out and substitute their originals, because the use of `rectangle` seems to conflict with `invclip`.

Comment: ok, so since the question of rectangles is irrelevant for my actual usecase, I'll change the question accordingly.

Comment: You don't need `pgfplots` here, either.

Comment: done editing the question accordingly

Comment: There is an unofficial package `spath` that helps you connect two or more paths into one. In this case, you are connecting a huge rectangle with whatever complicated path you used to have. After all this is a matter of softpath operation.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with standard packages?

Comment: @Symbol1 Is that distinct from `spath3`?

Comment: @cfr According to [Loop Space's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26627/saving-and-reusing-combining-paths-in-tikz/26664#comment615743_26664), it is distinct but the same. (What am I talking about...)

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks - I'd completely forgotten that comment.

Comment: @carsten Well, `spath3` is in TeX Live, on CTAN etc., so it is as standard as most packages.